# How to show data without (key value) pair in jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have data set of array:

```
[
  {0:0, 1:"test-1", 2:1, 3:"data-1"}, 
  {0:1, 1:"test-2", 2:2, 3:"data-2"},
  {0:2, 1:"test-3", 2:3, 3:"data-3"},
];
```

How can I display data in a jQuery Datatable? I am not able to populate with this type of dataset.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you post your JS? Could you also explain how your data works? Is test-1 the key and data-1 the value?

Comment: We need to see your code in order to help you debug it. That said, part of the problem will be that the dataset you have is not valid JS.

Comment: @Wimanicesir they are all data(only value no key) with indexing. like this [0,1,2,3]

Comment: @rajhim : There's [no problem](https://jsfiddle.net/5d8vp2te/) whatsoever to display above dataset (considering your comment about object keys) with DataTables. Can you explain in more details what's your expected result and where exactly you have failed?

Answer (score 1):

Datatable provide many ways how to generate table from dynamic source of data.

Example your data is from javascript, please refer documentation and example from this link:

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

And from your sample basic data, we can generate some basic table below:

```js
var dataSet = [
  {0:0, 1:"test-1", 2:1, 3:"data-1"}, 
  {0:1, 1:"test-2", 2:2, 3:"data-2"},
  {0:2, 1:"test-3", 2:3, 3:"data-3"},
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Index" },
            { title: "Test Name" },
            { title: "Sample No" },
            { title: "Data" },
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```